# Multiple projects with shared azure arm templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

This is a fun one.
I am new to deploying resources using ARM templates, but I have managed (with some difficulty!) to get them working to a satisfactory degree.
I have a question about best practices though and can't seem to find any articles on it.

If I have 2 projects that share a resource (in this case an SQL server), is it best practice to have that said resource in both templates or should there be some sort of shared project that uses first come first serve when building and deploying?

Currently I use the former. 
The reason I bring this up, is I can imagine that doing it my way will eventually cause some issues, because if I change one template, then I have to change them all.

Comment: Do you mean both projects try to deploy a fresh SQL Server?

Comment: Yeah, it's set to incremental so it doesn't remove resources

Comment: So if you deployed project 1, it would deploy a new SQL Server, and then if you deployed project 2, it would use that same SQL Server (but otherwise create it if didn't exist) and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create everything in separate templates and dont like to reuse templates because it really brings nothing to the table. I can copy\paste the same snippet into 2\3\10 different templates its no big deal, I can use mass find\replace to amend something. although, I've never had the case where some certain resource would needed to be changed in exactly the same fashion across all the existing projects. and usually projects have at least something in common (storage\vm\public ips\etc) and usually they do require different way to configure them, so I'd say dont try to reuse templates. little gain, but might hurt you in future a lot.

Comment: If you are using same resources by all applications copying is a problem. Say you use service bus, or SQL Server. If you change it in one copy then you need to update all copies. Otherwise if you first deploy with modified template and then with older copy it will revert the changes.

Answer (score -1):

I would think of this in terms of "lifecycle".  I.e. does the SQL Server have the same lifecycle as the databases? It sounds like it does not... which would suggest not only would it be a separate template, but you would not deploy that template each time you deploy a database.

ARM templates are code so follow best practices you use for other code (where sharing and reuse have their place).

When I am playing around and kicking tires I usually end up duplicating things like you're doing now, but once I make things "production ready" I'll clean up those things as it will eventually cause problems like you're thinking.  Depends a little on your workflow, but code is code...